# Multiple data sets not working when using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using chart js to produce a line graph and I want to display multiple datasets showing different data. After looking online I found a solution below, but for some reason it is not working. In the console I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ctx is not defined at 1:80`.

If anyone can see why the chart is not working, that would be great.

JS:

```
document.getElementById('productDetailGraph').getContext('2d');
    var productGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['01, 10', '02, 10', '03, 10', '04, 10', '05, 10', '06, 10', '07, 10', '08, 10', '09, 10', '10, 10', ],
            datasets: [{
                data: ['123, 124, 125, 126, 128, 122, 127, 121, 125, 127'],
                label: 'Argos',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(128, 128, 128)',
            }, {
                data: ['121, 122, 124, 122, 129, 131, 134, 137, 138, 140'],
                label: 'Smyths',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(128, 128, 128)',
            }, {
                data: ['122, 129, 125, 134, 135, 138, 139, 142, 145, 154'],
                label: 'Entertainer',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(128, 128, 128)',
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is ctx? #productDetailGraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `ctx` which is indeed not defined.

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById('productDetailGraph').getContext('2d');
```

To this:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('productDetailGraph').getContext('2d');
```

Comment: @MaxLoyd If you think that is the correct answer, please accept it :D